# r lapply map_dfr id = "filename" not working

Tags: r, lapply

I am combining 44 excel files into 1 df. I want to set an id col with the file name from each of the excel files so i can identify in final df.

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)

df.list.add <- lapply(file.list, read_excel,"Additions")
 
all_additions <- map_dfr(df.list.add, ~.x %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)), .id = "filename")
```

In all_additions the filename returned is numeric location in list of files rather than file name. It was working earlier. Do you know how I can fix this so that the id will be file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` transfers names (from `file.list`) when they exist and numbers otherwise. Use `setNames(nm=)`; the first argument (`object=`) is typically the object itself and the second argument (`nm=`) is the names to apply, but if `object=` is not provided, then it is effectively the same as `setNames(obj, nm=obj)`.

```r
df.list.add <- lapply(setNames(nm=file.list), read_excel,"Additions")
```